# Brownian Motion hitting random point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I got a problem that seems to be quite standard and easy, but I have lots of problems with it. I do already know that $T_a:=\inf\{t\geq 0: B_t=a\}$ is a  stopping time for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ fixed, $B_t$ being a standard BM.

But what about for instance $T_{B^{o}_1}$, where $B_t^{o}$ is an BM independent from $B_t$? Clearly $\{T_{B_1}\leq t, B^{o}_1=x\}=\{T_{-x}\leq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$. But the union over all $x$ is uncountable and I'm not sure if it could work if I only look at rational $x$.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $B_t^o$ is adapted to $F_t$ and $t > 1$ then the classical $\mathbb{Q}$ trick works because of the continuity of brownian paths:
\begin{align*}
\lbrace T_{B_1^o} \leq t \rbrace
&=  \lbrace \max_{s \in [0,t]}{B_s \geq B_1^o} \rbrace \cap \lbrace B_1^o \geq 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace \min_{s \in [0,t]} B_s \leq B_1^o \rbrace \cap   \lbrace B_1^o \leq 0 \rbrace
\\&= \cup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}^+}  \lbrace{\max_{s \in [O,t]} B_s \geq q\rbrace} \cap \lbrace q \geq B^o_1 \geq 0 \rbrace \cup \cup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}^-}  \lbrace{\min_{s \in [O,t]} B_s \leq q\rbrace} \cap \lbrace q \leq B^o_1 \leq 0  \rbrace
\end{align*}
The "max" and "min" sets are in $F_t$ because $B$ is $F_t$-adapted. $B_1^o$ is adapted also so the sets $\lbrace q \geq B_1^o \geq 0 \rbrace$ and $\lbrace q \leq B_1^o \leq 0 \rbrace$ are in $F_1 \subseteq F_t$ because $t > 1$.

In hindsight $\lbrace \max_{s \in [O,t]} B_s \geq B_1^o \rbrace$ is $F_t$ measurable since the max and $B_1^o$ are. This property is shown by the $\mathbb{Q}$-trick early in a course of measure theory.

Comment: Hmm so I just didn't dare to use the "$\mathbb{Q}$-trick". Just to be clear, because of the continuity of the BM the set $\{B_1=q_n\}\rightarrow\{B_1=x\}$ if $q_n\rightarrow x$, what justifies the first equality?

Comment: It is a bit slopy, I'm editing it now.